# Proving linear transformation on $C[0,1]$ is not invertible

Tags: linear-transformations, inverse-function

Let $X=C[0,1]$ be the space of continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$, $t_0\in J$. I am trying to show that if $T: X\to X$ defined by $Tx=vx$, where $v\in X$ is fixed, and $v(t_0)=0$, then $T$ is not invertible.

Here is the claim that I saw: Let $y=Tx=vx$. Then

> (claim): $T^{-1}$ exists if and only if $x=y/v$ for all $t\in [0,1]$.

But because $y/v$ is not defined at $t_0$, T is not invertible. I don't understand why the claim is true. I see no reason why $y(t_0)=(vx)(t_0)=0$ can't hold without making our transformation, non-invertible.

Edit: The transformation is not surjective. My goodness.

Comment: The vector spaces $X,Y$ have the same dimension hence your second statement is false (assuming the axiom of choice).

Comment: Present your attempts to prove that $T$ is not bijective.

Comment: @AnneBauval I have edited the question.

Comment: **Hint**: if $v(t_0)=0$ for some $t_0$ then —as $f\in\mathcal{C}([0,1])$— $T(f)$ cannot be any arbitrary element of $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$.

Comment: Hint:  be $x$ continuous or not, $y(t_0)=0$ prevent $y$ to be an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{C}([0,1]).$

Comment: Your "claim" did not really make sense because (as it is, and among other reasons) it seemed to pretend that the existence of $T^{-1}$ depends on an equation on some *fixed* functions $x,y$.

Comment: $T$ is clearly not onto $X.$ Whether it is even injective as a map $X\to T(X)$ depends on $v$. If $v$ is a triangle for example, supported in $(1/4,3/4),$ it is easy to construct a non-zero $f\in X$ such that $vf=0.$ On the other hand, if $v(x)=x$ and $vf=0,$ then $f=0$ on $(0,1]$ and so continuity forces $f=0$ at $x=0,$ too.

Comment: @Matematleta I noticed the point you make about a non-trivial null space, as well as that it was only true for certain $v$ because of continuity (which implies that if there is a neighborhood where $v$ is zero then the null space is non-trivial)